# GZIP HTML Files on Hard Disk - not on a web server

Tags: html, gzip

I have quite a few html files with datasets and huge tables and about 8-9 MB in size. These are currently saved on my hard disk and are not being served through a web server.

I am looking to deflate/gzip these similar to what a webserver does. The end goal is to reduce the size and when opened in a browser, the file opens and displays the relevant html content. Sort of like double clicking the gzipped html file opens it up in a browser which decompresses it and displays the proper html page.

Apologies if this comes across as asking too much.

Thanks

Krueger

Answer (score 1):

not really. depending on your OS, you can do different thing that can emulate it though.

1. you could turn on file level compression, but this is useless if you copy them off your system.
2. windows explorer will open a zip file like a folder, so if you just zipped it, it would sort of work like your looking for.
3. you could create your own format, call it htmlgz, gzip the file, and then associate the htmlgz extension with a batchfile/shellscript that would decompress the file to a temp location, then open the file in a browser.
4. write an application, that stores the data as a payload, and when executed will display the data, a little like a self extracting archive.